# How do you npm install the node_module folder to another drive without multiple copies of the same API?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

Node projects in my workspace use a variety of different version dependencies, which includes multiple copies of the same node module in my workspace, making it impossible to search for my files and trashing my SSD. Is there a package manager that stores node packages in a centralized repository on a selectable disk?

Comment: You can use [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/), it uses symlinks

Answer (score 0):

The [pnpm](https://pnpm.io/) package manager installs node packages to a centralized repository so you don't have to re-download the same npm repositories for multiple projects.